# Variable not "saving" during receiving information from Firebase with Swift

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

When I try to get information from my Firebase server, I load the data into certain variables so I can access them later.  It seems that I am only able to access the variable data in the Swift function where it gets the data from the Firebase Database.  Below I have a print function, that print function prints the correct data but when I try to print that data later in the code, it will not print anything.

(I am using Swift 3.0 and Xcode version 8.1)

My code for that specific spot:

```
func loadAllDataFromServerAboutGame(){

        ref.child("\(gamePIN)").observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in
            // Get user value
            let value = snapshot.value as? NSDictionary
            self.player1Name = value?["player1Name"] as? String ?? ""
            self.player2Name = value?["player2Name"] as? String ?? ""
            self.player3Name = value?["player3Name"] as? String ?? ""
            self.player4Name = value?["player4Name"] as? String ?? ""
            self.player5Name = value?["player5Name"] as? String ?? ""
            self.player6Name = value?["player6Name"] as? String ?? ""

            self.playerAmountBeforeTextChanging = value?["numberOfPlayers"] as? String ?? ""

            self.player1UID = value?["player1UID"] as? String ?? ""
            self.player2UID = value?["player2UID"] as? String ?? ""
            self.player3UID = value?["player3UID"] as? String ?? ""
            self.player4UID = value?["player4UID"] as? String ?? ""
            self.player5UID = value?["player5UID"] as? String ?? ""
            self.player6UID = value?["player6UID"] as? String ?? ""

            if let myNumber = NumberFormatter().number(from: self.playerAmountBeforeTextChanging) {
                self.numberOFPLayers = myNumber.intValue
            } else {
                print("Error converting text into 'int' value!")
            }

            print("Transcription: \(self.numberOFPLayers)")
            print("Player 3 Name: \(self.player3Name)")

            // ...
        }) { (error) in
            print("DataBase ERROR:\(error.localizedDescription)")
        }

    }
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You need to upload your whole view controller. It seems like you are printing out the variables before they have been set. This is because the observe event is asynchronous so any code outside the closure may be called before the closure has completed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to remember that the `observeSingleEvent`is fired asynchronous, and therefore it might be a good idea to put it into a Dispatch Group.

What I would suggest you do, is the to execute the method `loadAllDataFromServerAboutGame` from within a group, and not do anything until after it has finished firing, and all data has been written to the variables.

**Where you call loadAllDataFromServerAboutGame**

```
let group = DispatchGroup()
group.enter()
loadAllDataFromServerAboutGame()

group.notify(queue: .main, execute: {
    // Do something
}
```

Your `loadAllDataFromServerAboutGame` method:

```
func loadAllDataFromServerAboutGame(){

    ref.child("\(gamePIN)").observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in
        // Get user value
        let value = snapshot.value as? NSDictionary
        self.player1Name = value?["player1Name"] as? String ?? ""
        self.player2Name = value?["player2Name"] as? String ?? ""
        self.player3Name = value?["player3Name"] as? String ?? ""
        self.player4Name = value?["player4Name"] as? String ?? ""
        self.player5Name = value?["player5Name"] as? String ?? ""
        self.player6Name = value?["player6Name"] as? String ?? ""

        self.playerAmountBeforeTextChanging = value?["numberOfPlayers"] as? String ?? ""

        self.player1UID = value?["player1UID"] as? String ?? ""
        self.player2UID = value?["player2UID"] as? String ?? ""
        self.player3UID = value?["player3UID"] as? String ?? ""
        self.player4UID = value?["player4UID"] as? String ?? ""
        self.player5UID = value?["player5UID"] as? String ?? ""
        self.player6UID = value?["player6UID"] as? String ?? ""

        if let myNumber = NumberFormatter().number(from: self.playerAmountBeforeTextChanging) {
            self.numberOFPLayers = myNumber.intValue
        } else {
            print("Error converting text into 'int' value!")
        }

        print("Transcription: \(self.numberOFPLayers)")
        print("Player 3 Name: \(self.player3Name)")
        //HERE:
        group.leave()

        // ...
    }) { (error) in
        print("DataBase ERROR:\(error.localizedDescription)")
        //HERE:
        group.leave()
    }
}
```